# Why does Major Armstrong sparkle?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

I don't remember seeing any reasoning behind why Major Armstrong sparkles (although I've only ever seen the first anime series; I haven't read the manga nor seen the Brotherhood anime series).

> Also, when we meet other members of his family, they also sparkle, if I remember correctly.
>  And later on Breda even lampshades the sparkles, when he's cosplaying as Major Armstrong.

**Was there any in-universe explanation ever given for Major Armstrong's sparkles?**

[image: Sparkles]

Comment: It seems to me like the answer is just "because it's funny." Is there any reason you think there's a deeper reason?

Comment: Because I apparently had no idea there was a sparkles trope, as listed below!

Comment: CUZ HE'S FABULOUS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no in-universe reason for it, in the 2003 anime, the 2009 anime, or the manga. None of them give a reason for it, nor does any [Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod). In fact, Sig Curtis in *Brotherhood* sparkles a couple times as well, in addition to the rest of the family.

It's worth noting that there is a [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Trope) called "[Bishie (bishōnen) Sparkle](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BishieSparkle)". I doubt many people would classify Armstrong as bishōnen, but that article does mention that it does represent the personality of the one who sparkles (as a bit of a cutesy "he's beautiful inside" fluff). Here's an excerpt from that very article:

> - In *Fullmetal Alchemist*, THE ART OF SPARKLING BEAUTY HAS BEEN PASSED DOWN IN THE ARMSTRONG LINE FOR GENERATIONS! And it *really* has, although Major Armstrong is more 'manly' than pretty.
>
>   - It's not just Major Alex Louis Armstrong who has this trait, but THE ENTIRE ARMSTRONG FAMILY THROUGH THE GENERATIONS.
>   - Not just the entire family: the sparkle is possessed by a *flower woman* whose family has SERVED THE ARMSTRONG LINE FOR GENERATIONS. And one of her hairs has the Armstrong curl, too.
>   - Sig Curtis also develops a sparkle when he's doing manly things with Armstrong. Curiously enough, his sparkle isn't pink, but brown-ish.
>   - May's Inner-Mind Theatre version of Edward and later Alphonse have this.
>   - Roy Mustang gets some sparkles in the 13th episode of the 2003 anime adaptation during his duel with Edward.
>   - As does Envy in the Chibi Wrap Party OVA, to hilarious effect.
>   - Lampshaded by Breda when he's impersonating Armstrong to prank his colleagues: He's got small pink paper cutouts that look like Armstrong's sparkle, suspended on wires.
>       Armstrong also sculpted a statue of himself in The Movie from the 2003 anime series; it had a small four-pointed piece of stone for a sparkle suspended by a strip of metal coming from the body.
>   - *Fullmetal Fantasy*, the Fan Film produced by the English vocal cast, has Real Life Armstrong complete with sparkles, quite possibly the film's Crowning Moment of Funny.

Also, inarguably, it's funny. And the [Rule of Funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny) applies.